# How to find string with readfile if we know only a part of the string?

Tags: python, string, readfile, readline, readlines

How can I find a string in a text file if I know only the part of the string? For example, I know only `".someserver.com"`

But the whole text in the file looks like the following:

`"hostname1.expedite.someserver.com"`

So the point is to find the whole name by knowing only a part of it.

**part of the file content:**

```
{"attributes": {"meta_data": {"created_at":1614882362.179626, "created_by": "admin"}, "site": "AF002"}, hostname:"hostname1.expedite.someserver.com",
```

Comment: could you please example of file content, not only needed part?

Comment: yes , please. I have added a sample

Comment: Do you know the name of the property you're looking for? Do you know in this case that you are looking for the property `hostname:"..."`?

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like:

```
{"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.someserver.com"}
{"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.another.com"}
{"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.server.com"}
{"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.we.com"}
{"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.dont.com"}
{"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.care.com"}
```

We can:

```py
import ast

check = ".someserver.com"

with open("string.txt", "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        if check in line:
            print(dict(ast.literal_eval(line))["hostname"])
        line = f.readline()
```

this prints us:

```
:hostname1.expedite.someserver.com
```

---

Assuming the data looks like:

```
[{"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.someserver.com"}, {"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.another.com"}, {"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.server.com"}, {"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.we.com"}, {"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.dont.com"}, {"attributes": "xyz", "hostname": ":hostname1.expedite.care.com"}]
```

We then can:

```py
import json

check = ".someserver.com"

data = json.load(open("string2.txt", "r"))
for d in data:
    if check in d["hostname"]:
        print(d["hostname"])
```

This gives us:

```
:hostname1.expedite.someserver.com
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly Albo! But the file content is in bulk, not line by line unfortunately. :(

Comment: Then probably just read in the entire blob with `json.load(f)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your source is a file sample.txt that contains lot of hostname, simplest way is by using regex "hostname.*someserver.com", where the wildcard (*) is anything before hostname and the someserver.com example.

```
import re

f = open("sample.txt", "r")
textfile = f.read()
x = re.findall("hostname.*someserver.com", textfile)
print(x)
```

Comment: It works well, if the data is line by line in the sample.txt. But unfortunately it is in bulk in my sample.txt so it is printing out the whole file in this case.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about what is "Bulk". Do you mean, you need to consume multiple text file?

Comment: I mean the data is not line by line, it is just continously following each other in the text file.